# Parse host name from FQDN from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse out the hostname from an FQDN contained in a string like below. Where `testing` would be the hostname.

`454sdf testing.tst.hom.io QM_jjds as node one dot testing.tst.hom.io some more text`

I got this far `(.*?)\.tst\.hom\.io` but this doesn't seem to get me very far.

Comment: `(.*?)` will match literally anything, including `454sdf testing` and `QM_jjds as node one dot testing`. Try `([\w-]+)`

Comment: @e2-e4 the `\s` would be redundant if using `\w+`. Also, hostnames can contain hyphens

Comment: use this `.[^\.]+` the first match will be `test`.

Comment: I ended up coming up with this `.*\ (.*?)\..*` but it groups on the second FQDN. Any way to have it stop on the first match?

Comment: If you want the first occurrence, you can omit the `/g` flag. For the pattern, perhaps you could use a capturing group `([a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)(?:\.[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)+` See https://regex101.com/r/Qq1olG/1

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `(.*?)\..*` with not flags and it worked perfect. Thanks everyone for all you feedback.